# uncrustify: newline before opening brace for function definitions

Tags: uncrustify

Using uncrustify 0.60

I set nl_fcall_brace=force expecting the following result: newline between function arguments and the opening brace of function body

```
string toNsdName(const string& sid) 
{
   if (sid.empty())
   {
      return "";
   }
   string temp(sid);
   replace_all(temp, PERIOD_MARK, DASH_MARK);
   return temp;
}
```

--- Instead code remains ---

```
string toNsdName(const string& sid) {
   if (sid.empty())
   {
      return "";
   }
   string temp(sid);
   replace_all(temp, PERIOD_MARK, DASH_MARK);
   return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Apparently what was needed is "nl_fdef_brace=add"